# I want to print each state next to its own value

Tags: python, jupyter-notebook

I have dataset of covid-19 and I've used for loop to thro all states and divided total deaths & total cases and I use append to store the results and it's showing the result what I want is to print every state next to its own value

here is my code
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/rPeX8.png)

Comment: [Please do not upload images of code/errors when asking a question.](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/285551/why-not-upload-images-of-code-errors-when-asking-a-question)

Comment: Colors is a great song

Answer (score 0):

You can try something like the following :

```
s = []
for i in range(len(r)):
    value = r['tot_death'][i]/r['tot_cases'][i]
    s.append((value, r['state']))
```

And I agree with Reza Rahemtola, please dont upload screenshots of code, instead just give it as text.

Comment: hi Phoenix, it's showing error and the key error is state

Comment: I put 'state' because I don't know the name of your columns. Just replace 'state' by the column name where you have all the states names